# How can I get DISTINCT results from JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

How can I to get distinct results of the last ten visitors, with a count of how many times they've visited?

This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT all_ref  FROM site_stats WHERE all_ref!='' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

returns last ten most recent visitors

```
all_ref
Chicago, IL     
Chesapeake, VA  
Austin, TX  
San Jose, CA    
Houston, TX 
Newport News, VA    
Sebastian, FL   
Dublin, IE  
Menlo Park, CA
Waves, NC
```

This will return the count for all visitor:

```
SELECT all_ref, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM site_stats WHERE all_ref!='' 
AND all_ref!=',' GROUP BY all_ref ORDER BY ct DESC, all_ref
```

This is what I'm tryng to get the last 10 visitors with how many times they've visited:

```
SELECT x.all_ref, x.ct
FROM (SELECT all_ref, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM site_stats WHERE all_ref!='' GROUP BY all_ref )
AS x LEFT JOIN site_stats AS f
ON f.all_ref=x.all_ref
ORDER BY f.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

It returns this (the all_ref and ct values returned ARE correct):

```
all_ref     ct  
Chicago, IL 26  
Chicago, IL 26  
Chesapeake, VA  18  
Chesapeake, VA  18  
Austin, TX  2   
San Jose, CA    3   
Houston, TX 1   
Chicago, IL 26  
Chicago, IL 26  
Chicago, IL 26
```

but should return something more like this:

```
all_ref         ct  
Chicago, IL     26    
Chesapeake, VA  18  
Austin, TX      2   
San Jose, CA    3   
Houston, TX     1      
Chicago, IL     26
Pittsburgh, PA  11
Richmond, VA    52
Waves, NC       24
Grandy, NC      9
```

Making it DISTINCT x.all_ref is not the answer.

**UPDATE**:
The solution that works for me:

```
SELECT x.all_ref, x.ct
FROM (SELECT all_ref, MAX(id) AS id, COUNT(*) AS ct 
FROM site_stats 
WHERE all_ref!='' GROUP BY all_ref )
AS x LEFT JOIN site_stats AS f
ON f.all_ref=x.all_ref
GROUP BY x.all_ref
ORDER BY x.id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have a doubt that using f.id without using in select will give you the correct result.

Comment: [View on DB Fiddle] (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gVjXtxQzSBN47PA3Ts9Q3A/0)

Comment: If the code in your last edit is the solution to your problem then post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works for me:

```
FROM (SELECT all_ref, MAX(id) AS id, COUNT(*) AS ct 
FROM site_stats 
WHERE all_ref!='' GROUP BY all_ref )
AS x LEFT JOIN site_stats AS f
ON f.all_ref=x.all_ref
GROUP BY x.all_ref
ORDER BY x.id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may first find the distinct then join the table -

```
SELECT f.id
      ,x.all_ref
      ,x.ct
FROM (SELECT all_ref
            ,COUNT(*) AS ct
      FROM site_stats
      WHERE all_ref!=''
      GROUP BY all_ref ) AS x
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id, all_ref
           FROM site_stats) AS f ON f.all_ref=x.all_ref
ORDER BY f.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Just to let you know, this was the implementation of COUNT window function. If you MySQL version supports Window function, you may simply use -

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
               ,all_ref
               ,COUNT() OVER() AS ct
FROM site_stats
WHERE all_ref!=''
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```